# Objective C isKindOfClass confusion

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have code that gets a TableViewCell using the cellForIndexPath API.  I am using storyboards and expecting the cell to be custom type of EditItemTableViewCell.  This class inherits from UITableViewCell.

The debugger (and all I can find) says my variable is a EditItemTableViewCell, yet isKindOfClass says my cell is not an EditItemTableViewCell.  Here is some code I put together to test what is going on:

```
    BOOL bCellOK                = [cell isKindOfClass:[EditItemTableViewCell class]];
    NSString *strCellClass      = NSStringFromClass([cell class]);
    NSString *strReferenceClass = NSStringFromClass([EditItemTableViewCell class]);
    NSLog(@"cell    class is %@",strCellClass);
    NSLog(@"desired class is %@",strReferenceClass);
    if ([strCellClass isEqualToString:strReferenceClass])
        NSLog(@"Both the cell class and the reference class are the same, so bCellOK should be YES.  The value is %@", bCellOK ? @"YES" : @" NO");
    else
        NSLog(@"The cell class and the reference class are the different, so bCellOK should be  NO.  The value is %@", bCellOK ? @"YES" : @" NO");
```

The debugger output shows:

```
2021-11-21 13:56:26.039446-0500 XXXXXXXXXXX[21961:3210758] cell    class is EditItemTableViewCell
2021-11-21 13:56:26.039564-0500 XXXXXXXXXXX[21961:3210758] desired class is EditItemTableViewCell
2021-11-21 13:56:26.039598-0500 XXXXXXXXXXX[21961:3210758] Both the cell class and the reference class are the same, so bCellOK should be YES.  The value is  NO
```

Xcode is version 13.1 (13A1030d)

I have successfully used isKindOfClass in the past.  Am I doing something wrong?  Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: Presumably, if you write an if-statement whose condition is `bCellOK`, it will fall into the `else` case, correct? (The debugger _can_ be wrong on occasion, and may report some variables as containing `0`/`false`/`nil` even when this is not the case.) And if so (and `bCellOK` is truly false): presumably `EditItemTableViewCell` inherits from `UITableViewCell` directly, and does not override any Objective-C runtime methods which would cause dispatch to go to the wrong type, correct?

Comment: Itai -  Thanks for your response.  Correct, bCellOK is NO after the above code executes.   I found this problem using isKindOfClass with NSAssert.  I double checked - EditItemTableViewCell inherits directly from UITableViewCell and does not override any methods.

Comment: Interesting! This is definitely unexpected; certainly nothing in the code indicates anything you're doing wrong. Are you able to extract this behavior into a small example project that you would be able to share? Or does this only happen in your project? (And if this is the case, do you use any 3rd-party libraries in the project? Something could be messing around with _all_ subclasses of `UITableViewCell`, potentially)

Comment: Great idea.  I will extract the part of the code to a tiny demo project.  If the issue goes away I will take a deeper dive into my project.  I will be happy to share the code/project if the error repeats itself.

Comment: Excellent! I hope you manage to get to the bottom of this, but if you manage to reproduce it, I would be very curious to dig in to see what might be happening.

Comment: Well...I put together a test project to investigate this and now isKindOfClass works as expected.  Not sure what/how this has become a problem, but seems clear to me that the issue is somewhere inside my project or something else in my control.  Oh well.   Thanks for the input/suggestion!

Comment: That sounds frustrating, but I hope you have a little bit more direction to go on now... For what it's worth, if you create a brand new, empty subclass of `UITableViewCell` in the project and try to use that, does the issue still happen? (And if you use a plain `UITableViewCell` itself?) This might help you narrow down what might be going on a little bit further...

Comment: One other thought, regarding debugging: using the debugger, are you able to _step in_ to the `isKindOfClass:` call? If you _can_, this would indicate that something that you have source access to has overridden/overwritten the method, and you might be able to see where it's coming from. If not, then the method is the one coming directly from `NSObject` and you might know something else is going on.